# ¿Como validar header personalizado class base view django rest framewor?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo una API desarrollada en Django Rest Framework, desde la cual puedo exponer algunos datos "públicos", los clientes que consuman estos servicios pueden obtener esta información sin necesidad de autenticar el usuario (sesión)

Sin embargo quiero que cualquiera que consuma un servicio pase un atributo header obligatorio el cual contenga un valor que pueda validar.

Como puedo validar desde mis APIView o viewsets que las peticiones recibidas posean dicho atributo y que este sea valido

viewset:

```
class CiudadesViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    Obtención del listado de ciudades
    """
    queryset = models.Ciudad.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CiudadSerializer
```

APIView:

```
class SolicitudesView(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request):
         ...
         return response
```

Comment: también me topé con ese asunto ahora que estoy probando DRF, y buscando un poco acabo de encontrar esto https://riptutorial.com/Download/django-rest-framework-es.pdf, en el capítulo 2 comienza sobre autenticaciones personalizadas, aún no lo implemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en el libro que me recomendó [soyunewok](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183893/soyunewok) lo resolví de la siguiente forma

https://riptutorial.com/Download/django-rest-framework-es.pdf

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsClient(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        key = request.META.get('HTTP_KEY')
        return key == 'npfm+&zons(fqrgv2!un-mt5m_%3b^=z#@9f4+83==78o5)=^='


class CiudadesViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsClient,)

    queryset = models.Ciudad.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CiudadSerializer


class SolicitudesView(views.APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsClient,)

    def post(self, request):
         ...
         return response
```